# How to get terminal access to ISO mounted with Archive Mounter?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, mount, iso

When I mount a .iso image with Archive Mounter using Nautilus, I get a new entry under Network. I can use this in Nautilus but cannot find a way to cd to it from a terminal.

I tried installing nautilus-open-terminal but it won't work for directories mounted in this way!

Note, there are already solutions on AskUbuntu using the terminal to create a loopback device. I don't want to do this and am only interested in a way I can mount with Archive Mounter and then access with a terminal.

Comment: So I guess you don't want to extract the iso? This would allow access through a terminal with the cd command.

Comment: .iso is useful if I need to burn quickly. So extracting would result in two 'copies' of everything - one compressed as iso and one extracted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Archive Mounter** uses `gvfs` to mount the ISO images.

On 14.04+, you'll find it mounted under

```
/run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs/
```

Where `id -u` return return [your username's UID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier). If you are the only user on the system, this is probably `1000`.

There's an environment variable called `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` that should hold the path `/run/user/<UID>`, so you can just do:

```
ls $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs
```

And you'll find your ISO mounted there to a directory starting with `archive:host=file...`

Comment: Thank you Alaa Ali! That's exactly what I need. The last command's output was very verbose and didn't take me anywhere but the first part contains my solution.

Comment: mounted volumes dont seem to mount here on Debian Jessie Cinnamon's default (Gnome) Files file browser. Additionally "Terminal Here" context item drops right into the home directory. Edit, it lists this under "Network" in the sidebar, and yeah, any idea where one can find where `archive://` "network locations" are mounted?

Comment: This may be related: http://superuser.com/a/720528/309066

Comment: I can confirm that for Fedora (v25 at least) the answer is bang on.

Comment: On 16.04, the gvfs dir is empty. A 16.04 friendly update to the answer would be great :)

Comment: still working for ubuntu 18