# How do I find the location of a mounted folder?

Tags: mount, software-installation, matlab

I am attempting (and failing) to install MATLAB on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The guide given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509902/how-to-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-14-04) is clear except that I cannot find the location of the mounted folder.

I downloaded an iso file from the web and it is sitting in my Downloads. I Right-Clicked it and opened it with Archive Mounter. It now appears as a folder on the left hand panel (with an eject option).

The next step for me would be to find the mounted folder from the terminal and run the install file, however I can't find any path to put in the terminal.

I have been using Linux for 2 days so sorry if this demonstrates a complete misunderstanding.

Comment: I was just about answet it and then I found a "possible duplicate of [**How to get terminal access to ISO mounted with Archive Mounter?**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/518356/how-to-get-terminal-access-to-iso-mounted-with-archive-mounter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount the iso by command line:

```
sudo mount -o loop myIsoFile.iso /media/iso
```

then you will know were you mounted it.

Comment: Hi Bruni, I did that and the path I got was this: archive://file%253A%252F%252F%252Fhome%252Futher%252FDownloads%252FR2015a-glnxa64.iso/     which seems nonsensical to me. I put it in the terminal and it said it didn't exist.

Comment: @Matta just changed my answer to something that should work.